# Source for checking talis over shoulder

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, tallit-gadol, parts-of-the-body, inspection

What is the source for checking one's tzitzis while the talis is over one's right shoulder: isn't the halacha just to check the knots and strings? Can't the checking be done on a table?

Comment: What makes you think there is any reason to do so? Just because you've seen people doing it that way? I personally don't.

Comment: If many ppl do it I thoght maybe there is a mekor,but it could be just for conv.

Comment: I have actually wondered if it was a possible problem to do that, because it appears as though you're wearing it (albeit more like a sash) before making the Berachah.

Comment: @SethJ why would that look like wearing? If someone slings a shirt over their shoulder it doesn't look like they are wearing anything.

Comment: I'm just telling you how I perceive it every time, which makes me wonder if it's an issue. My point is merely that I avoid doing it that way. I hold it in my arms or lay it across my seat to check the strings.

Comment: @SethJ Based on [pseudo](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14738/759)-Rama to [OC 13](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%92):2 I don't think it should be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nitei Gavriel Hilchos Nesuin Volume 2 Chapter 61](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46546&st=&pgnum=61) mentions this Minhag in the name of the Shela.

Comment: Thank you for  source.I had a feeling there was a real mekor for this. I looked inside it looks like the putting over the right shoulder is a minhag Chabad ,and saying the pesukim while checking is from the Kitzur HaShla.

Comment: Is it only Chabad?  I've seen it by other chasidim.