# Candles in bedroom during Tisha B'Av

Tags: marriage, yom-kippur, tisha-bav, candle-lighting, lighting

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20387/candles-in-bedroom-over-yom-kippur) question discusses the practice of keeping a candle lit in the bedroom on Yom Kippur. It suggests--although I dispute this somewhat--that the main  purpose of this candle is to discourage marital relations on that day.

If so, does one also light such a candle for Tisha B'Av (another time when [relations are prohibited](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tisha_BeAv#Marital_Relations))?

Comment: Having a candle lit on tisha bi'av doesn't help as it can easily be extinguished.

Comment: Keep in mind that on Yom Kippur the candle must be lit before sunset. On Tisha B'av one can light a candle later that night. The question is more like do we need to light a candle before going to bed.

Comment: Also: YK is a Torah prohibition, 9-Av is a Rabbinic one.

Comment: @Danny not all prohibitions on Yom Kippur are necessarily biblical...

Comment: @user6591 Good point. However, for those who foerget about prohibitions (whom the candle seems to be targeting) one could just as well extinguish it-or ignore it--on Yom Kippur too

Answer (score 2):

> does one also light such a candle for Tisha B'Av

A cursory check of classic Halacha books shows that none of them mention it.

Au contraire, what is mentioned - reagrding light -  is that on Tisha B'Av one minimizes light; providing just enough for the Kinot to be read.

<sup>This may explain the difference. Yom Kippur being a Yom Tov (at some level) everything is brightly lit and one can see one's wife in her (white) Yom Kippur clothes, as opposed to Tisha B'Av when she's not dressed up and one can barely she her.</sup>