# Where can I find a complete Shulchan Aruch without too many abbreviations?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, shulchan-aruch

I am looking to buy a Shulchan Aruch, but unlike [Buying a Shulchan Aruch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40881/buying-a-shulchan-aruch), I am concerned with different requirements

1. I don't want a lot of abbreviations. I have spent some time learning Yoreh Deah already, and I found it one of the more difficult things to deal with (especially when preparing beforehand)
2. Should not be expensive
3. Has to be a complete set
4. Clear printing. Does not have to be large, but can't be fuzzy, or misaligned, or overall just terrible to read (think of all the very old gemara printings. Not like that)
5. Has the Tur
6. Doesn't matter if it has the Tzurat Hadaf.

The order is listed in what I care about most to least.

Are there sets that match this?

Comment: "Has the Tur" in the same set? Is this important to you? I mean, most prints of the _Tur_ don't have the _SA_, and most prints of the _SA_ don't have the _Tur_. (At least, most prints I've seen.)

Comment: try sefaria!! http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer

Comment: I own this one, it's not cheap ,but it's great http://www.eichlers.com/tur-shulchan-aruch-habair-26-vol-set-tvr-vwvlhn-ervk-hbhir-26-krkim.html

Comment: @msh210 not so much.  I've just seen it in the front of some sets

Answer (score -1):

Oz V'hadar has a full Shulchan Aruch, linked [here](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/shulchan-aruch-oz-vehadar-16-volume-set/62064). That would be your best bet. As far as I understand, it is the same as "the Friedman Shulchan Aruch", linked [here](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/shulchan-aruch-friedman-edition---26-volume-set-SAFE-SL.html), but in much smaller print.

Comment: Where did you get the idea it was the same? It is not ! Also the OP asked for a combined Tur SA - this Oz ve Hadar edition doesn't have the Tur