# Difference between two sets of the Tur

Tags: product-recommendation, tur

A pretty popular set of the Tur is the [Shirat Devorah](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/18080/%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%94-%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%93%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%92%27-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D-) edition. It has a beautiful typeface, corrected girsaos, useful features like Seif indicators, summaries of each simman, notes from achronim, etc.

I recently saw in a shul a different [set by Meor](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/18098/%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%94-%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99-22-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D---%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%94). It's also a beautiful set, and seems to have similar features. They're also around the same price.

What do people recommend? Has anyone used both? What's the difference between the two? Does one set have a must have feature the other doesn't have?

Comment: I've never owned a Tur, but they both look so awesome. Good luck!

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40881/11532

Answer (score 7):

Different strokes for different folks. I personally prefer SD. I've used both but the HaMaor only when I don't have the SD. Some differences: SD sticks to basic textual corrections and critical (and sometime classical) glosses on Tur & commentaries; very "non-crowded" pages; doesn't carry itself like an encyclopedia. On the other hand, I find HaMaor to contain: while they too "clean" the texts on the page I find their notes to have too many unnecessary "round ups" of commentaries at the bottom of each page; formatting of pages feel dizzying (like the Oz VeHadar gemara); compilation at the end of each volume is more for reference type - something I find dispensable, unlike the compilation of Mechon Yerushalayim's Shulchan Aruch. In summation: the two editions cater to different folks. It boils down to the reader's preference.

Alternatively, see עט סופר's review here (I second his sentiments):

http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=6298