# Whose publisher's Tur and Shulchan Aruch should I get?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, shulchan-aruch, tur

Looking for something with clear printing and that has the mishna brurah in it also.

Comment: [Difference between two sets of the Tur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85591/difference-between-two-sets-of-the-tur)

Comment: I believe only Shulchan melachim has the Mishnah berurah in it

Comment: @robev Only the new edition of Shulchan Melachim has the Mishna brueah in it.

Comment: @Efraym correct