# Which Talmud-edition to buy?

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, shulchan-aruch, tur

What Talmud-edition is advisable for a simple baalbayit, who is trying to make his way through the Gemara. I am aware of the Schottenstein-edition and its adavantages, but I mean an edition without translation. What size do you need if you still want to be able to read your Rashi when you're 90?

I have the same question for beginners level Tur and Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: related for Shulchan Aruch: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40881/buying-a-shulchan-aruch and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85591/difference-between-two-sets-of-the-tur

Comment: I believe that sadly steinzaltz is the largest font and volume size talmud out there, thus, especially for a 90 year old, I would recommend that among a slue of other reasons

Comment: I wouldn't ignore the value of getting smaller sets. There are several "peninim" 6 volume Gemaras with just Rashi+Tosfos that are handy for reference especially as a beginner. The Mir Edition Shulchan Aruch is just 10 volumes, and there are smaller ones with just the Baer Hetev; more useful than one would think and avoiding the excesses of a 30+ volume set.

Answer (score 2):

The best recommendation is always to go to a seforim store and see what you like, there are so many criteria that one person's preference might not work for you. Personally I find that I learn best from full-size editions especially when trying to access the commentaries which are nearly always in smaller font. But your mileage may vary depending on your sight.

This being said, if helpful to you, you could consider an edition with vowels and punctuations such as [Oz Vehadar's](https://ozvehadar.us/talmud-bavli-oz-vehadar-shas-menukad/) which are full-size. They also exist in an edition with *mefarshim* (e.g., Rosh, Rif, Ran) which has been printed on many but not all volumes yet.

For Tur and Shulchan Aruch see related answers [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40881/buying-a-shulchan-aruch) and [there](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85591/difference-between-two-sets-of-the-tur). Personally I have a full SA but only buy the Tur (Friedmann or Machon Yerushalayim) in areas I learn in depth.

Comment: What voweling tradition does Oz Vehadar use?

Comment: In truth I don't know - there are six pages of introduction in small font on that topic only ... seems like a very deep science

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest either the Steinsaltz (full size) or the Chavruta  (full size and most mesechtot are multi-volume)

Comment: Shmuel, I don't follow your comment as I did not suggest the Schottenstein edition.

Comment: @Shmuel There is a Hebrew-edition R Steinsaltz edition of the Talmud, different from Schottenstein, that the OP is referring to

Comment: I was confused somehow and did not saw your answer correctly :) my apologies

Comment: Shmuel, no worries, and the large Hebrew version that mbloch referred to is what I had in mind