# Which Rishonim held of shkia/tzeis according to the zman of Rabbeinu Tam?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, zemanim, rishonim, rabbeinu-tam

Which Rishonim held of shkia/tzeis according to the zman of Rabbeinu Tam?

Ive heard the Shulchan Aruch (rishon/acharon) held of it, did he pasken like for starting shabbos?

Comment: Um. Rabbeinu Tam? :)

Comment: @Shokhet besides for him and the Mechaber

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Majority of Poskim like Rabbeinu Tam?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82409/majority-of-poskim-like-rabbeinu-tam)

Answer (score 4):

Rabbi Moshe Meiselman in his book *Torah Chazal & Science*, pg. 345, footnote 143 writes:

> ... Rabbeinu Tam's view was endorsed by the Ramban (*Toras HaAdam* in *Kisvei HaRamban,* Jerusalem: Mossad HaRav Kook, 1964, pp. 251-254), the Rashba (*Chiddushim, Shabbos* 34b) and numerous other *Rishonim.* It is the position of both the *Shulchan Aruch* and the Rama (261:1-2). In fact, the Radvaz writes that he is unaware of any *Rishon* other than R. Eliezer of Metz (d. 1198) who unambiguously advocated a different position (*Teshuvos HaRadvaz,* Part IV, 1353 or *Orach Chaim* 282).

Rabbeinu Tam's opinion is also held by the Ritva (Shabbos 35a) as well as the Ran (Shabbos 15a, according to the pages of the Rif.)

Answer (score 2):

The Shulchan Aruch in  [סימן רסא זמן הדלקת נרות לשבת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0019_L2) states that **Shabbat starts** [the time it takes to walk] 3/4 Mil [1,500 Amoth] after the sun has set.

> **א:** סְפֵק חֲשֵׁכָה, וְהוּא  בֵּין הַשְּׁמָשׁוֹת, (הַיְנוּ **כְּדֵי שִׁעוּר הִלּוּךְ ג' רְבִיעֵי מִיל אַחַר שְׁקִיעַת הַחַמָּה** (טוּר בְּסִימָן רצ''ג וּכְדִלְקַמָּן סוֹף סִימָן ב') (וְשִׁעוּר מִיל הוּא שְׁלִישׁ שָׁעָה פָּחוֹת חֵלֶק ל') אֵין מְעַשְּׂרִים אֶת הַוַּדַּאי וְאֵין מַטְבִּילִין אֶת הַכֵּלִים וְאֵין מַדְלִיקִין אֶת הַנֵּרוֹת וְאֵין מְעָרְבִין עֵרוּבֵי תְּחוּמִין וְע''ל סי' תט''ו ס''ב, אֲבָל מְעַשְּׂרִין אֶת הַדְּמַאי וְטוֹמְנִין אֶת הַחַמִּין וּמְעָרְבִין עֵרוּבֵי חֲצֵרוֹת וְע''ל סי' שצ''ג. וּמֻתָּר לוֹמַר לְעַכּוּ''ם, בֵּין הַשְּׁמָשׁוֹת, לְהַדְלִיק נֵר לְצֹרֶךְ  שַׁבָּת; וְכֵן לוֹמַר לוֹ לַעֲשׂוֹת כָּל מְלָאכָה שֶׁהִיא לְצֹרֶךְ מִצְוָה אוֹ שֶׁהוּא טָרוּד וְנֶחְפָּז עָלֶיהָ.‏

The **Tur** seems to agree, as we see from the source in parentheses. He's [also] a Rishon.

However, one has to add some time before that, according to some opinions,  for Tosefeth Shabbath, as he states in Siman ב, where he also defines what he considers as sunset.

> ב יֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לְהוֹסִיף מֵחֹל  עַל הַקֹּדֶשׁ; וּזְמַן תּוֹסֶפֶת זֶה הוּא **מִתְּחִלַּת הַשְּׁקִיעָה שֶׁאֵין הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ נִרְאֵית עַל הָאָרֶץ עַד זְמַן בֵּין הַשְּׁמָשׁוֹת**; וְהַזְּמַן הַזֶּה שֶׁהוּא ג' מִילִין וְרָבִיעַ, רָצָה לַעֲשׂוֹתוֹ כֻּלּוֹ תּוֹסֶפֶת, עוֹשָׂה. רָצָה לַעֲשׂוֹת מִמֶּנּוּ מִקְצָת, עוֹשֶׂה; וּבִלְבַד שֶׁיּוֹסִיף אֵיזֶה זְמַן שֶׁיִּהְיֶה וַדַּאי יוֹם מֵחֹל עַל הַקֹּדֶשׁ. וְשִׁעוּר זְמַן בֵּין הַשְּׁמָשׁוֹת הוּא ג' רְבִיעֵי מִיל שֶׁהֵם מַהֲלַךְ  אֶלֶף וְת''ק אַמּוֹת קֹדֶם הַלַּיְלָה.‏

After the sun is no longer visible, one has 3.25 Mil before Shabbath starts,

The Mishna Brura explains the above in detail.

Interestingly enough, the Shulchan Aruch Paskens that if one does not know when this time is, one should light candles when the sun is still shining on the tree tops. This would seem like a long time before Shabbath starts.

> **ג:** וּמִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ בָּקִי בְּשִׁעוּר זֶה, יַדְלִיק בְּעוֹד שֶׁהַשֶּׁמֶשׁ בְּרֹאשׁ הָאִילָנוֹת; וְאִם הוּא יוֹם הַמְעֻנָּן, יַדְלִיק כְּשֶׁהַתַּרְנְגוֹלִין יוֹשְׁבִים עַל הַקּוֹרָה מִבְּעוֹד יוֹם. וְאִם הוּא בַּשָּׂדֶה, שֶׁאֵין שָׁם תַּרְנְגוֹלִים, יַדְלִיק כְּשֶׁהָעוֹרְבִים יוֹשְׁבִים מִבְּעוֹד יוֹם.‏

Regarding **Motzai Shabbat**, the Shulchan Aruch mentions in  סימן רצג - דיני ערבית [במוצאי שבת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0051_L2) waiting for 3 small stars close together.

> **ב:** צָרִיךְ לִזָּהֵר מִלַּעֲשׂוֹת מְלָאכָה עַד שֶׁיֵּרָאוּ שְׁלשָׁה כּוֹכָבִים קְטַנִּים, וְלֹא יִהְיוּ מְפֻזָּרִים אֶלָּא רְצוּפִים, וְאִם הוּא יוֹם הַמְעֻנָּן יַמְתִּין עַד שֶׁיֵּצֵא הַסָפֵק מִלִּבּוֹ. ‏

Comment: @Danny_Schoemann Its possible his shkia isnt normative shkia according to the Gaon from Vilna,

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "clearly". He writes Bein Hashemashot lasts 3/4 of a Mil immediately after Shkiya (whenever that is). Plus it's not even him that's writing but "parenthesis guy" ([whoever that is](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14738/759)). And the citation to the Tur was NOT written by R Yosef Karo; any citation in ShA is an addition by printers.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I don't know how _clearly_ snuck back in. I added in Siman 2 where he is very explicit (no parenthesis guy) as to when Shabbat begins.

Comment: @jerry - I have no idea what you mean. You asked if anybody holds of Rabeinu Tam for starting Shabbat. I answered that it seems that the Shulchan Aruch does. See my edits.