# Majority of Poskim like Rabbeinu Tam?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, zemanim, rishonim, tosfot

Recently someone made the statement that "rov poskim" go like the shita of Rabbeinu Tam in regards to shkia/nightfall. Is there any list available that shows the Rishonim and Achronim that pasken like Rabbeinu Tam? On the same night is there an opposing list of those that normally pasken like the "shitas hagaonim" as it's often known (the opposing view to Rabbeinu Tam in regards to shkia/nightfall

Comment: While I didn't downvote, this doesn't show much research effort, (did you google something like דעת רבנו תם שקיעה).

Comment: How do you expect to count this? There have been thousands of rabbis who had practices in this regard. Even documenting every individual one is basically useless as a proof because so many have been missed

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53609/

Comment: There is a sefer called זמנים בהלכה by Chaim Beinish (he did a great job on everything about the zmanim), there you'll find a comprehensive list of all the kehillot that follow the R Tam or the Geonim (i'm not sure if it is in part one or two or in which siman, but it is easy to find in the list of contents).

Answer (score 2):

R. Ovadya Yosef has a (characteristically) lengthy responsum analysing the views of numerous authorities (Yabi'a Omer vol. 2 OH 21).

He writes (ibid: 5) the following summarising the Rishonim  and major Aharonim who concur with R. Tam:

> . נמצא שדעת רובא דרבוותא קמאי שמשעת שקיעת השמש מעינינו עד צאת הכוכבים הוי שיעור ד' מילין, וקודם לזה אסור מה"ת לעשות מלאכה במוצ"ש. (הלא הם רבינו האי גאון. ור"ת. והראב"ד. והרז"ה. והרמב"ן. והרשב"א. והרא"ה. והריטב"א. והר"ן. והרב המגיד. והמאירי. וה' אהל מועד. והסמ"ג. והרוקח. והמרדכי. ורבינו פרץ. והרא"ש. ור' ירוחם. ועוד.) ולזה הסכימו מרן והרמ"א בש"ע. והמבי"ט. והרדב"ז. ומהר"י קולון.

He writes further (ibid 8) regarding the Aharonim:

> והנה רבים מגדולי האחרונים ס"ל ג"כ כד' ר"ת. וכמ"ש בשו"ת הבית חדש (סימן קנד) וז"ל: ולענין הלכה רוב המחברים תפסו פי' ר"ת, וכן פסק הב"י בהל' שבת, וכן מנהג כל ישראל. ע"ש

Regarding those who disagree with R. Tam, he references (ibid 10):

> שאחר שכבר נהגו להחמיר בזה כסברת כמה פוסקים. ומהם רב נסים גאון, ור"א בן הרמב"ם, והובאו להלכה בתשו' מהר"ם אלשקר. ולזה הסכים רבינו הגר"א (סי' רסא). וכ"כ בס' חידושי רז"ה (דכ"ט ע"א והלאה). עש"ב וכן האריך בזה המשנ"ב בבאה"ל (סי' רסא). והעלה שח"ו להקל באיסור סקילה לדעת כמה רבוותא. והבא /והביא/ שכן פסקו עוד הראב"ן, ומהר"ל מפראג, והש"ך ביו"ד (סי' רסו ס"ק יא). ע"ש

Additionally, he notes (ibid 11) that in practice the view of the disputants of R. Tam held much sway, and that likely reflected the views of numerous other authorities, whose views are not extant in our records:

> איברא דחזי הוית להגאון בתי כהונה ח"ב (ס"ס ד) שכתב, שאע"פ שלפי הספרים הנמצאים עמנו נראה שרוב הראשונים תפסו לעיקר כשיטת ר"ת. מ"מ הואיל ובמספר הדורות סוגיא דעלמא דלא כוותיה, ונראה שפשטה הוראה בכל תפוצות ישראל כדעת החולקים. אית לן למימר שמאז ומקדם גמרו אומר רוב הראשונים דלא כר"ת, אלא שלא זכינו לדבריה' בכתובים. ע"ש.

He notes (ibid) that this was also the view of the Ben Ish Hai, and the custom in Baghdad:

> וכן העד העיד בנו הגאון החסיד רי"ח ז"ל בבן איש חי ש"ב (ר"פ ויצא) שהמנהג להמתין במוצ"ש עד כ' דקים /דקות/ אחר המגרב. ומר אביו הרב החסיד ז"ל היה מחמיר להמתין חצי שעה. ע"ש.