# Hallel before chatzos at seder

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, zemanim, passover-seder-hagada, hallel

I was reading Rav Schwab On Prayer (page 541) where he says the following about the timing of parts of the Seder:

> According to some *poskim*, even the recitation of *Hallel* should be completed before *chatzos*.

Which *poskim* hold that way?

Answer (score 3):

[Pseudo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14738/759)-Rama rules that way in [OC 477:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%96):

> ויקדים עצמו שגם ההלל יקרא קודם חצות
>   And he should [eat the Afikoman] early enough so that he reads Hallel as well before midnight.

Comment: ...quoting the Ran on the Rif ([*P'sachim* 27b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37955&st=&pgnum=413) s.v. גרסינן, and [*M'gilla* 7a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37957&pgnum=520) s.v. וכן).

Comment: @Fred:  who's 'quoting the Ran on the Rif?'

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Pseudo-Rama is (accd to the printers, at least).