# In birkat kohanim, who calls out "kohanim"?

Tags: minhag, chazzan-prayer-leader, hefsek-interruption, birchas-kohanim

Should the chazan be the one to say kohanim or a member of the tzibbur? If you hold that it should be a member of the tzibbur due to Hefsek why would it be a Hefsek for the chazan to say kohanim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Rambam ([Tefillah 14:8](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2214.htm#8)) says explicitly it's the Chazzan who calls.

Tosfot ([Berachot 34a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=34&format=pdf)) quote Rabbeinu Tam who says that the Chazzan cannot call out "Kohanim" as it is a Hefsek. He proves this from the Sifri (Naso 39) which says Kohanim is said by the "Chazzan" (in context "Chazzan" there is like what we call "Gabbai"), and from the Talmud in Sotah (39b) which calls the one who calls out "Kohanim" the "Korei", as opposed to the one who prompts the words of the blessing the "Shatz". Tosfot continues to cite opinions that this was true only when it wasn't common for the Chazzan to recite "Eloheinu..." regularly in his repetition, but now that it is [possibly because the Kohanim had stopped Duchening every day? -- AA] he can just say that paragraph and say the word "Kohanim" out loud in order that it not be a Hefsek.

R Meir HaKohein of Rothenberg, in his Haghot Maymoniot (Tefillah 14:8), notes that his teacher, Maharm of Rothenberg, told him of his practice to recited "Eloheinu..." quietly and "Kohanim" out loud in order not to deviate from the custom that the Chazzan calls "Kohanim", but when questioned by R Meir haKoehin how he could say that paragraph at all when it was designed only for instances when no Kohanim were present, Maharam admitted and abandoned that practice.

The Tur (OC 128) quotes Tosfot and Maharam's original practice but leaves off the end of the story.

The Beit Yosef says the common practice is like the Rambam, and so he rules in his Shulchan Arukh ([OC 128:10](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x494)), while the Rama there notes some who practice like Maharam's initial practice. The Bach (OC 128) too says the custom is like Maharam's initial practice. Both these customs are still commonly practiced in the Diaspora in my experience. The Gra ([Maaseh Rav 168](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91#.D7.A7.D7.A1.D7.97)), however, rules like Rabbeinu Tam and the final practice of Maharam that the Gabbai should call out "Kohanim", and such is commonly practiced in Israel, in my experience.

Comment: IME common Israeli practice is that someone other than the chazzan says "Kohanim", but certainly not followed by everyone. I've seen chazzanim who said it themselves, and i remember a Chabad guy who actually said the whole "Elokeinu..." formula.

Comment: @Scimonster It's Judaism. You expect anything to be universal?

Comment: See also Rashi Sotah 38a כהן קורא כהנים - אם שליח צבור כהן הוא קורא ומזהיר את חביריו העומדים לפניו להחזיר פניהם ולברך את ישראל ואם ישראל הוא אינו קורא כהנים:

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a dispute in the Shulchan Aruch - [סימן קכח - דיני נשיאת כפים](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_7.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2)

> **י':** עוֹמְדִים בַּדּוּכָן פְּנֵיהֶם כְּלַפֵּי  הַהֵיכָל וַאֲחוֹרֵיהֶם כְּלַפֵּי הָעָם, וְאֶצְבְּעוֹתֵיהֶם כְּפוּפִים לְתוֹךְ כַּפֵּיהֶם, עַד שֶׁשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר מְסַיֵּם מוֹדִים וְאָז אִם הֵם שְׁנַיִם
>    קוֹרֵא לָהֶם <sup>**הַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר**: (בַּטּוּר בְּשֵׁם ר''י וְרמב''ם).</sup>  כֹּהֲנִים. **הגה**: <sup>וְלֹא יֹאמַר אֱלֹקֵינוּ וֵאֱלֹקֵי וְכו'; וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁאוֹמְרִים אוֹתוֹ בְּלַחַשׁ עַד מִלַּת כֹּהֲנִים, וְאָז יֹאמְרוּ בְּקוֹל רָם (טוּר בְּשֵׁם ר''י וְר''מ מֵרוֹטֶנְבּוּרְג) וְחוֹזֵר וְאוֹמֵר: עַם קְדוֹשָׁךְ כָּאָמוּר,  בְּלַחַשׁ, וְכֵן נוֹהֲגִין בִּמְדִינוֹת אֵלּוּ.</sup> וּמַחֲזִירִים פְּנֵיהֶם כְּלַפֵּי הָעָם; וְאִם הוּא א', אֵינוֹ  קוֹרֵא לוֹ, אֶלָּא הוּא מֵעַצְמוֹ מַחֲזִיר פָּנָיו.‏

Note how the critical words הַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר are in smaller type - so it's not from the Machaber - supposedly it's from the [Remo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14738/759) - but it's unclear if he's arguing or clarifying.

BTW: The words הַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר seem to be accredited to the Tur and the Rambam. I didn't (yet) look in the Tur, but the Rambam in [הלכות תפילה וברכת כהנים - פרק ארבעה עשר](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01999.html#HtmpReportNum0017_L2) seems to imply that it's **not** the שְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר  who says these words. (So *(בַּטּוּר בְּשֵׁם ר''י וְרמב''ם)* may be referring to the beginning of the phrase.)

The entire time the Rambam mentions הַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר and then for our point he says:

> **ה':** אֵין **הַמַּקְרֵא** רַשַּׁאי (לְהַקְרוֹת לַכֹּהֲנִים) עַד שֶׁיִּכְלֶה אָמֵן מִפִּי הַצִּבּוּר. וְאֵין הַכֹּהֲנִים רַשָּׁאִין לְהַתְחִיל בַּבְּרָכָה עַד שֶׁיִּכְלֶה הַדִּבּוּר מִפִּי הַמַּקְרֵא.‏

Making it sound like the שְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר doesn't call the Cohanim. More puzzling, as the  לחם משנה  and  כסף משנה  point out, is that the Rambam actually says that nobody calls the Cohanim, and they start by themselves.

> **ג':**  כֵּיצַד הִיא נְשִׂיאַת כַּפַּיִם בַּגְּבוּלִין. בְּעֵת שֶׁיַּגִּיעַ שְׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר לַעֲבוֹדָה כְּשֶׁיֹּאמַר רְצֵה כָּל הַכֹּהֲנִים הָעוֹמְדִים בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת נֶעֱקָרִין מִמְּקוֹמָן וְהוֹלְכִין וְעוֹלִין לַדּוּכָן וְעוֹמְדִים שָׁם פְּנֵיהֶם לַהֵיכָל וַאֲחוֹרֵיהֶם כְּלַפֵּי הָעָם וְאֶצְבְּעוֹתֵיהֶם כְּפוּפוֹת לְתוֹךְ כַּפֵּיהֶם **עַד שֶׁיַּשְׁלִים שְׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר הַהוֹדָאָה וּמַחְזִירִין פְּנֵיהֶם כְּלַפֵּי הָעָם וּפוֹשְׁטִין אֶצְבְּעוֹתֵיהֶן וּמַגְבִּיהִין  יְדֵיהֶם כְּנֶגֶד כִּתְפֵיהֶם וּמַתְחִילִין**  'יְבָרֶכְךָ'. וּשְׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר מַקְרֵא אוֹתָם מִלָּה מִלָּה וְהֵם עוֹנִים...‏

Note how here too he uses the term שְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר.

The Kitzur in [108:8](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0099_L2) says that it's the Chazzan who says it, but he says כֹּהֲנִים as part of the regular אֱלֹקֵינוּ וֵאֱלֹקֵי אֲבוֹתֵינוּ, just saying the rest quietly.

> **הַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר אוֹמֵר** אֱלֹקֵינוּ וֵאֱלֹקֵי אֲבוֹתֵינוּ, בָּרְכֵנוּ בַּבְרָכָה וְכוּ' בְּלַחַשׁ, וְתֵיבַת **כֹּהֲנִים** אוֹמֵר בְּקוֹל רָם, וּבָזֶה הוּא קוֹרֵא אֶת הַכֹּהֲנִים שֶׁיְבָרֵכוּ. וְשׁוּב אוֹמֵר בְּלַחַשׁ, עַם קְדוֹשֶׁךָ כָּאָמוּר‏

The Aruch Hashulchan [108:18](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0127_L2) says like the Remo that the Chazzan should only say כֹּהֲנִים - but if he has the custom to say the rest, it must be done quietly.

> **י"ח:** כשעולים על הדוכן – עומדים פניהם כלפי ההיכל, ואחוריהם כלפי העם, ואצבעותיהם כפופים לתוך כפיהם דלא כמו בשעת הברכה. עד שמסיים שליח הציבור ברכת ''הטוב שמך...'', והציבור עונין ''אמן'', **והשליח ציבור אומר בקול ''כהנים''** – ואז מחזירין פניהם כלפי העם ואחוריהם כנגד ההיכל. דכך צוה הקדוש ברוך הוא: ''כה תברכו'' – פנים כנגד פנים אמור להם, כאדם האומר לחברו (סוטה לח א). וכמה חביבים ישראל לפני הקדוש ברוך הוא שהרשה לכהנים לעמוד אחוריהם כלפי היכל בשביל ברכות ישראל.‏ 
>   **והשליח ציבור לא יאמר כלל ''אלהינו ואלהי אבותינו ברכנו...''**, כי אין לו ענין לברכת כהנים. ואפילו **אותן הנוהגים לאמרו יזהרו לומר בלחש**. וכשיגיע ל''כהנים'' יאמר ''כהנים'' בקול, ו''עם קדושיך כאמור'' בלחש. וכן נוהגין במדינות אלו.‏ 
>  
>   ויש משליחי ציבור טועים, שאומרים בקול ''אלהינו...'', ויש להזהירם על זה. וכן מוכח להדיא בסוטה (לט ב) שאומר שם: אין הקורא רשאי לקרות ''כהנים'' עד שיכלה ''אמן'' מפי הציבור – הרי שקריאת כהנים סמוך ממש להברכה. ‏

So it seems that there's no hefsek for the Chazzan to say כֹּהֲנִים; yet it seems from the Shulchan Aruch (and Rambam?) that there are opinions that somebody else should say it.

Comment: It should probably be טור בשם ר"י ור"ם referring to Maharam of Rothenberg.