# Does the congregation say "am kedoshecha ka'amur" before birchas kohanim?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, birchas-kohanim

Does the congregation say "am kedoshecha ka'amur" before birchas kohanim?  Or only the chazzan?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Eric. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: How about no one says it?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68637/759

Answer (score 3):

In the Shulchan Aruch in [Orach Chaim 128:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.128?lang=he) the Remo says `וחוזר ואומר עַם קְדוֹשֶׁךָ כָּאָמוּר בלחש`, i.e. that the Chazzan says it quietly.

The Mishna Brura ([ibid 27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.128.10?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.128.36&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=he)) says that the Chazzan says עַם קְדוֹשֶׁךָ, and he adds that those locations where the Cohanim say it, are mistaken.

> **לו:** **וחוזר ואומר עם קדושך** - היינו הש"ץ ומה שנוהגין באיזה מקומות שהכהנים אומרין עם קדושך טעות הוא:‏

That said, I've been in many a shul where the congregation said עַם קְדוֹשֶׁךָ כָּאָמוּר out loud, and the officiating Rabbi never objected.