# Are the eight nights of lighting Menorah one Mitzvah or eight?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia, lomdus

By Sefiras HaOmer, there is a dispute whether it’s a single Mitzvah to count fifty days, or whether one fulfills the Mitzvah of counting each day independently (Rosh, Pesachim 10:41, et. al.). As a practical difference, if one forgot to count one night, or if one became a Bar Mitzvah in the middle of counting, can he continue counting - according to the former position, the answer would be no, while according to the latter position, the answer would be yes.

Does this dispute extend to Menorah? Do Rishonim or Geonim address whether it’s one Mitzvah to light Menorah for eight days, so if one missed a day he would be unable to continue lighting, or whether it’s one Mitzvah performed eight times, so if one missed a day he would be able to continue lighting?

Looking specifically for sources which directly state that one can/cannot continue lighting on Chanukah for this specific reason.

Comment: Ok, but realize this is false: "according to the former position, the answer would be no, while according to the latter position, the answer would be yes". There are plausible conceptual positions that it is multiple mitzvot but you can't keep counting and positions that it is one mitzva but you can. (I described them before.)

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%91_%D7%91 related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12720/759

Comment: Isnt the mitzvah on the bayis(if one doesnt have a home they are patur) and each night one has to light regardless since its parsumei nisa every night,even if one misses a night one has to light since every night there is a din of parsumei nisa. Also the ikar mitzvos is 1 ner every night so tech missing a night shouldn't make too much of a diff.

Comment: In a shiur that I attended this week I was told that it is a separate mitzvah each night and that this is the reason that full Hallel is said each day.

Answer (score 5):

The Tur (672) write :

> אם עבר כל הלילה ולא הדליק לא ידליק ביום המחרת דשרגא בטיהרא מאי אהני וכן לא ישלים בלילה של אחריו

That is, if he did not light up all the night, he wont light up the day, nor in the next night,

And on that the Beit Yossef write :

> ומ"ש בתשובה אשכנזית דלא בא הר"מ לומר אלא דאותו לילה אין לה תשלומין אבל אלילות אחירות לא קאי דנס כל יומא איתיה ולית דין צריך בושש וכן איתא באגודה **ולא דמי לעומר דהתם משום דכתיב תמימו' תהיינ' אבל הכא כל חדא מצוה באנפי נפש' היא** ומה שמוסיפין משום הידור הוא ע"כ

That what he "wont light up next night", that is for this night he wont have "refund", but that he will light up all the other nights as usual, and **it's not as the Omer where there are who think that's all counts are just one mitsva, but here, all night is a new mitsva**.